# Unable to change div dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div:

When you click a button the div appears to grow by animating its height and width:

```js
$("#addquestionstoset").button().click(function(){
  //only show set if it is currently hidden
  var clickedcards = getClickedCardIDs();
  if ($(".setinprogress").css("display") === "none") {
      $(".setinprogress").css("display", "block");
  }
  setsize += clickedcards.length;

  //grow the set
  if (clickedcards.length === 1) {
    $(".setinprogress").animate(
      {
        height:'+=10',
        width:'+=14',
        left:'-=5',
        top:'-=5px',
        fontSize:'+=3'
      },
      1400
    ).text(setsize);
  } else if(clickedcards.length > 1 && clickedcards.length <= 5) {
    $(".setinprogress").animate(
      {
        height:'+=20',
        width:'+=24',
        left:'-=10',
        top:'-=10px',
        fontSize:'+=5'
      },
      900
    ).text(setsize);
  } else if(clickedcards.length > 5 && clickedcards.length <= 10){
      $(".setinprogress").animate(
        {
          height:'+=25',
          width:'+=29',
          left:'-=13',
          top:'-=13px',
          fontSize:'+=7'
        },
        500
      ).text(setsize);
  } else if(clickedcards.length > 10){
    $(".setinprogress").animate(
      {
        height:'+=30',
        width:'+=34',
        left:'-=20',
        top:'-=20px',
        fontSize:'+=15'
      },
      300
    ).text(setsize);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="setinprogress" class="setinprogress" style="display:none; top:580px;left: 250px; box-shadow: 10px 10px black; z-index: 1;height:10px;width:10px;"></div>
```

Then when you click another button this div get's hidden(display:none) and I want it to get back to an original size:

```js
$("#setsavebutton").on("click",function(){
    setsize = 0;
    page = 1;
    questionsaddedclicks = 0;

    $("#setnamediv").effect("clip",500);
    $("#setbuttondiv").effect("clip",500);
    $("#setinprogress").effect("puff",400);

    $("#setinprogress").height(10);
    $("#setinprogress").width(10);
});
```

... but then if you click the button that makes it grow again it's at the height it was before it was hidden, as if .width() and height() had no effect.

Comment: `.button()` doesn't seem like a native jquery function, where did you get it? Will you also include necessary html?

Comment: It's jquery ui, makes the buttons look cool. That block works though.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/button/

Comment: My advice would be to not do any of this with jQuery but by CSS animations.

Comment: I believe the height() and width() takes numbers, not string. So change .height("10") to .height(10) and .width("10") to .width(10)

Comment: That doesn't work. I have some other calculations to do I don't think css would work.

Comment: I commented out "$("#setinprogress").effect("puff",400);" and it worked, must have something to do with 'display' being none. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, you need to wait for 500ms before setting width and height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a timeout or similar to wait for animation to complete. You can also use .queue function to wait.

https://api.jquery.com/queue/

I have created a jsfddle also.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("#setinprogress").css({
    width: 10,
  height: 10,
  fontSize: '12px',
  top: 0,
  left: 0
});
}, 500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tf8dcqj4/3/

Comment: I don't understand, why do you have to wait ?

Comment: Animations are async. You can only trigger it.